# Bash programming, interrogating ttyUSB port

Tags: bash, at-command, tty, interrogative-programming

I'm new in this of bash programming in linux, basically what I want to do is to program a bash file that can open the port ttyUSB0 and then I need to interrogate it with AT commands (like "0100") and then assign the response to a variable, I've been trying this with this different ways:

1) Using cat
`#!/bin/bash
PORT= \ls /dev/ttyU*
cat $PORT
????`

2) Using Minicom 
`#!/bin/bash
minicom
????
'

3) Using Screen 
`#!/bin/bash
PORT= \ls /dev/ttyU*
screen $PORT
????`

How can I interrogate it before the cat, minicom and screen starts? What should I have to put in ???? of the 3 different codes?

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try writing to a tty device using bash, you'll end up chasing your own tail forever. Use minicom or C-Kermit for that.

If you want to check that the device is active before starting minicom, you can read from it with bash and there is a good explanation of how to achieve this here: [Bash read from ttyUSB0 and send to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942502/bash-read-from-ttyusb0-and-sent-to-url)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how do I interrogate the ttyUSB0?, what I can see it's how to read the answer, that would it be with "READ=`dd if=/dev/ttyUSB0 count=22 | sed 's/ //g'`" But, What is the dd? What is the count=22 | sed 's/ //g'?

Comment: `dd` is a tool for copying a file and count=22 means to copy only 22 blocks from the file before termination. This is then piped to `sed` which strips spaces ('s/ //g' means strip all spaces).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use my [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) program for this. It is a command line tool to talk with a modem:

```
$ echo AT | atinout - /dev/ttyUSB0 -
AT
OK
$
```

So with a little bit of scripting you should be able to extract the response you want (remember to always check for a successful `OK` response).